# Send the child ViewModel not the childs $data in foreach binding expression?

Tags: knockout.js

How do I send the child ViewModel to a $parent's function in a foreach binding expression?

I can do this:

```
   <button class="radius button small" data-bind="click:function() { $parent.openDialogueEdit($data)}">Edit</button>
```

but it is not useful since in openDialogueEdit I will bind the $data to an observable that is used by the Edit Dialogue and the $data has the evaluated observables, not the observables themselves, which I need to bind the data in that foreach render to the edit Dialogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the item sent into a bound function is the current context, which is the child viewmodel in a `foreach` binding.

```
data-bind="click: $parent.selectedItem"
```

That's all you would need. You can take a look at this in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/wAZxH/).

Comment: and how would I best call $parent.openDialogueEdit($data) at the same time?

Comment: just take out the param, call it like `$parent.openDialougeEdit`, and then inside that function you can do whatever you like, such as set the `selectedItem`.

Comment: Cool, the thing is I need to use click:function() { because openDialogueEdit is a prototype method :(

Comment: The whole scope/prototype issue is one that still causes headaches. Michael Best has made some comments about it coming in version 3. Until then, I would just recommend putting your viewmodel methods on the instance.

Comment: ah the pain... I'm using typescript so these methods are put into prototype by convention..

Comment: I'm not familiar with typescript, but it should have some mechanism for making functions from the constructor instead of the prototype. If not, of if that's uncomfortable, there is a fork of KO that fixes the scope issue: https://github.com/mbest/knockout or see my second answer.

Comment: I can do that but I wanted to keep some logic out of there, but I think for now I can stick it in the constructor, I don't really want to use a fork but thx for the pointer!!

Answer (score 1):

To solve the prototype scope issue, you can add a bind to the constructor

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.removeSeat = this.removeSeat.bind(this);
};

ViewModel.prototype.removeSeat = function(seat) {
    this.seats.remove(seat);
};
```

This will force the function to properly associate `this` in the standard `click` binding. Its a bit awkward, but its the simplest solution, I think.